# Why does this code print 12 instead of 1?

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

```
class New{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int x=1;
        switch(x){
            default : System.out.print("default");
            case 1 : System.out.print(1);
            case 2 : System.out.print(2); 
        }
    }
}
```

This code works properly when I use the break keyword.
But I have no idea why this doesn't work properly.
Can someone explain the code to me?

Comment: Step through it in your debugger. Using a debugger isn't an advanced skill, learning to do it is basically the next thing every beginner should do after "Hello, World".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `switch` statement jumps to the `case` that matches, and continues processing from there until it sees a `break.` Since there are no `break`s in that code, it starts at `case 1`, outputs 1, and then continues with `case 2` and outputs 2. Although it's rare, *sometimes* this "fall through to the next `case`" is what you actually want. But usually, you want `break` to stop it.

It would say `"default"`, too, if you moved it to the end:

```
class New {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int x=1;
        switch(x){
            case 1 : System.out.print(1);
            case 2 : System.out.print(2); 
            default : System.out.print("default");
        }
    }
}
```

outputs

```
12default
```

Similarly, if you set `x` to `2`, it would skip the `case 1`:

```
class New {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int x=2; // <===
        switch(x){
            case 1 : System.out.print(1);
            case 2 : System.out.print(2); 
            default : System.out.print("default");
        }
    }
}
```

outputs

```
2default
```

Comment: But x=1 right?  So why does the case 2 get executed?

Comment: @ThisuraThenuka - As I said above, without the `break`, it continues executing the code from `case 1` onward. It continues into `case 2` (and in my later examples, into `default`). That's why you need `break` if you don't want that to happen, otherwise execution continues with the next case. Although it's rare, *sometimes* this "fall through to the next `case`" is what you actually want.